# There is no $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(123) \alpha^{-1}=(13)(578)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I have a question about permutations. I'm trying to prove there is no permutation $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(123) \alpha^{-1}=(13)(578)$.

I think I would have to use that $\alpha(123) \alpha^{-1} = (\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\alpha(3))$.

Is the fact that $(13)(578)$ is a disjoint 2-cycle permutation and $(\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\alpha(3))$ is one-cycle enough to argue there is no $\alpha$ that satisfies the condition?

Comment: Yup! As answered in your previous question, conjugation cannot change the cycle structure. So conjugating by $\alpha$ cannot turn a 3-cycle into a (2,3)-cycle.

Comment: Here's another, perhaps more elementary observation which you could exploit even if you didn't know about preservation of cycle structure or parity. The orders of the elements $(123)$ and $(13)(578)$ differ; the order of the former is $3$ and the order of the latter is $6$. Conjugation (like any isomorphism) must map each element to another element of the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: if two elements in a group are conjugate then they have the same order: $g^{-1}xg=y$ implies $o(x)=o(y)$. This is easy to prove and I leave it to you Cure. Now $o(123)=3$, but $o((13)(578))=6$.

Answer (score 0):

The parities differ. Note, that the parity of a $3$-cycle is even.

$$sgn(\alpha(123) \alpha^{-1}) = sgn (123) = 1 \color{red}{\neq} -1 = sgn(13)\cdot sgn(578) = sgn((13)(578))$$